# How to install OpenOffice in headless mode on a CentOS server

Tags: openoffice

how to download and install OpenOffice 3.1 in headless mode on my CentOS server...I am working with a java app that needs OpenOffice as just a service for form generation....I am having a difficult time...any head on what steps to take would be great...

Comment: Which CentOS version?

Comment: I have CentOS Linux 5.4 on a VPS box

Answer (score 2):

```
yum install openoffice.org-<package>
```

Examples:

```
yum install openoffice.org-base
yum install openoffice.org-calc
yum install openoffice.org-writer
```

Comment: each time I attempt to install I keep getting missing dependency errors...

Comment: Do I have to install JRE on the server..if so how to the java app I am attempting to set up uses Tomcat6 which is installed and configured...but having difficulty installing OpenOffice in headless mode...not sure what I am missing..thanks a ton

Comment: YUM should take care of dependencies automatically... what errors exactly do you get?

Comment: I get quite a few...I can email you them...they are too long for this comment area..

Comment: here are a few...

 java-gcj-compat is needed by package bsh-1.3.0-9jpp.1.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: java-gcj-compat is needed by package xalan-j2-2.7.0-6jpp.1.i386 (base)
Error: Missing Dependency: libhal-storage.so.1 is needed by package gnome-mount-0.5-3.el5.i386

Comment: That's ok, it's usual for YUM to show you missing dependencies; but then it should ask you to automatically install all of them, does it?

Comment: wow..it does not..

Comment: Very strange. Does your Linux box have Internet access?

Comment: looks like someone installed jvm manually and not as a packet.

you can try yum install --skip-broken but no guarantees

Comment: I tried to install with yum install --skip broken openoffice.org.base..with it seems no luck any suggestions?

Comment: You could... download the packages with wget, install them with rpm... then try again.  Sometimes rpm succeeds where yum does not.  Certainly when it comes to installing dependencies

Answer (score 1):

```
yum install openoffice.org-base
yum install openoffice.org-calc
yum install openoffice.org-writer

yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

You also need the last command to be able to run in headless mode. Otherwise you'll be getting:

```
/usr/lib64/openoffice.org3/program/soffice.bin X11 error: Can't open display:
   Set DISPLAY environment variable, use -display option
   or check permissions of your X-Server
   (See "man X" resp. "man xhost" for details)
```

Comment: -headless is no longer necessary (it's now part of the base)

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install openoffice.org-headless
```

Comment: do someone know how to count words openoffice.org ?